# Calling button only ticks for one second and can't display text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game and I want when I am in the garage if I buy more speed and I am already max, a text to pop up saying "Max speed reached!". But when I click on the button and have max speed, it doesn't stay but goes away after 1 tick. I can't figure out how to make it stay for longer because of how the button works. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the code for the button:

```
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # 1 is the left mouse button, 2 is middle, 3 is right.
                if event.button == 1:
                    # `event.pos` is the mouse position.
                    if button2.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        print('we been clicked')
                        current_time = time.strftime("%S")
                        # Increment the number
                        if player.vel < 20:
                            if player.coins >= 50:
                                player.vel += 5
                                player.coins -= 50
                                print('speed =' + str(player.vel))
                                player.vel1 = player.vel
                                player.grassvel = player.vel // 2
                                player.save()
                            else:
                                print("ur poor")
                        else:
                            MaxSpeedReached()
```

And here is the code for the function it calls:

```
def MaxSpeedReached():
    display_crash_text = False
    print("Max speed reached")
    if display_crash_text == False:
        start_time = time.strftime("%S")
        display_crash_text = True
    maxspeedtext = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    maxspedd, maxspeedr = text_objects("Max Speed  Reached!", maxspeedtext, BLACK)
    maxspeedr.center = ((205, 270))
    print(current_time, start_time)
    if display_crash_text == True:
        win.blit(maxspedd, maxspeedr)
        if int(start_time) - int(current_time) < 3:
            display_crash_text = False
            print("yo we checking the time difference")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you're seeing this because the message is drawn once when `MaxSpeedReached()` is called, but the only possible path to reach this function is on `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event.

You need to paint the message in the main loop, whenever the conditions for max-speed are occurring.

```
MAX_VELOCITY = 20

maxspeedtext = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
maxspedd, maxspeedr = text_objects("Max Speed  Reached!", maxspeedtext, BLACK)
maxspeedr.center = ((205, 270))

[ ... ]

# Main loop
while not finished:

    [...]

    if ( player.vel >= MAX_VELOCITY ):
        win.blit( maxspedd, maxspeedr )
```